# Is there a way in Xul to get notifications of new USB devices plugged?

Tags: usb, xul, xulrunner

Is there a way in Xul to get notifications of new USB devices plugged?

Comment: I don't think XULRunner provides one. Is there a particular OS's API that you're thinking of?

Comment: @Neil not, I'm on a Linux system. Own distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Neil said I don't think there is a way through the XULRunner API to get this notification.
However this should be possible using a C++ XPCOM component which would use the OS API to access to the USB information. Here is a good [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_XPCOM_Components) for creating your own component.

You can also try have a look at [Songbird](http://getsongbird.com/) source code in the "components" section, I can imagine they are accessing USB devices.